# Have asp script manager on master page and telerik radgrid on content pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik-grid

I am using scriptmanager on master pager which makes the tool created to be available on all content pages.

Now, i am trying to use the radgrid on my content pages. This grid works ok but the whole page reloads when any click or page change occurs on the grid.

I cannot add two script managers and am not sure if i am doing it right .

Please help!

Here is my code:

`

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="SqlDataSource1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>


<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Skin="Outlook">

    <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
    </ClientSettings>

<MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EditMode="PopUp">
    <Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MakeName" HeaderText="Make" 
                        SortExpression="MakeName" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="modelname" HeaderText="Model" 
                        SortExpression="modelname" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Minutes" HeaderText="Minutes" 
                        SortExpression="Minutes" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContractDuration" HeaderText="Duration" 
                        SortExpression="ContractDuration" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Texts" HeaderText="Texts" SortExpression="Texts" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="Data" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="GiftWorth" HeaderText="GiftWorth" 
                        SortExpression="GiftWorth" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MonthlyPayment" HeaderText="Monthly" 
                        SortExpression="MonthlyPayment" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        <telerik:GridImageColumn DataImageUrlFields="networklogo" HeaderText="Network" 
            ImageHeight="" ImageWidth="" UniqueName="column1">
        </telerik:GridImageColumn>
        <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="DeepLink" Text="Buy Now" 
            UniqueName="Buy Now">
        </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>

                </telerik:RadGrid>




            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" `
```

Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one script manager per page -- so adding 1 on your master page and another on your content page will cause errors..If your problem is just the "reloading" of the page each time you postback by clicking on something on your grid, why not use update panels? So your page is not "redrawn" each time you click on something.

See this link: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxpanel.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `telerik:RadAjaxPanel` incase you do not want to postback the whole page, it will only postback the contenet of the Panel. You can also use `telerik:RadAjaxManager` which will be useful if you want to postback particular part of page that depends on another control..

**Note:** you have used `RajAjaxManagerProxy`, proxies are used only when you already have one `telerik:RadAjaxManager` in Master page or parent page.